# SSH remote takes too much time to connect

Tags: vscode-remote

My local is Windows 10 and host is Linux (AWS EMR).
Using key based authentication.

I need to connect to linux machine for my dev work. Every time I connect to remote, it looks like it setups the VS Code Server *everytime* and it takes *a lot of time each time I connect*.

How can I prevent VS Code to setup itself each time I connect?

[what it shows when connecting to remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDggD.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something. It was a .ssh/config file issue on host system.
I reverted it to vanilla (bare minimum configs) and it was smooth after that.